# Spring Boot: Posting to a REST API is storing a single string as an array

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, post

I have a Spring Boot app I'm writing that uses Angular for the front end.

One REST API accepts an array of strings as input:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/import", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@CrossOrigin
public void importComicFiles(@RequestParam("filenames") String[] filenames)
{
    for (String filename : filenames) { ... }
}
```

When the front end sends an array of string values using the following:

```
importFiles(filenames: string[]): Observable<Response> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    for (let index = 0; index < filenames.length; index++) {
      formData.append('filenames', filenames[index]);
    }
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/files/import`, formData);
}
```

then the Java code receives each string as a separate element in the array. Even if those strings have spaces in them.

HOWEVER, when the importFiles method is called with a single string then the Java code behaves as if the value received is an array spit on a single space at the end of the string. An example input string is:

**/Users/mcpierce/Google Drive/comics/DC/2018-01-17/Superman Vol.2016 #39 (March, 2018).cbz**

Java treats this string as if it were two strings:

**/Users/mcpierce/Google Drive/comics/DC/2018-01-17/Superman Vol.2016 #39 (March,**

and

**2018).cbz**

If I change the Java code to just treat the filenames parameter as a string (rather than as a List or a String[]) then I get the whole string. If it's more than one then each is separated by a common (,).

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding the issue correctly, but the problem is that the Java code is splitting a single string, correct? If so, based on the example, the comma is probably causing the issue. Try removing removing commas on the client-side (Angular) before sending them to the sever.

Comment: try escaping the query params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say Spring is operating just fine. But the way we use the request params is wrong. Spring delimits the request parameters and injects as array.

GET http://example.com?filenames=1,2,3,4

Above can be injected into `@RequestParam("filenames[]") String[] filenames` with each one entry in array.

In your case it would be treated as different entries coz of the comma. Try posting it as request body object instead as a request param and use to get the array?

Comment: Posting the string array as the body of the request did the trick. I adjusted the controller and the javascript to do this and things work correctly for a single string or multiple strings.

Comment: Awesome. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding the [] to the parameter value as well.

```
@RequestParam("filenames[]") String[] filenames
```

Comment: This didn't work. I changed the code to this on the server side:

    public void importComicFiles(@RequestParam("filenames[]") String[] filenames)
    {
        logger.debug("Attempting to post to controller");
        for (String filename : filenames)   { ... }